# Drupal Ajax Cache

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm updating a module I've written from D6 to D7, and therefore have to exchange the old AHAH by the new #ajax in forms.

I'm performing an ajax request which creates a result and replaces a form element with it. This basically works fine, but after the first request, the result is cached and does not take changes in the form into account. I think this is probably a browser-issue, but could it be that Drupal sends an expiration header which induces the browser to take the cached version? Ot any other ideas?

The fragment in hook_cache():

```
  $form['fieldset']['mybutton'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',   
    '#value' => t('Send request'),
    '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'mycallback',
          'wrapper' => 'mywrapper',
          'method' => 'replace',
          'effect' => 'fade',  
    )
```

A snippet of the callback:

```
function mycallback($form, $form_state) {

        [..]

        $form['fieldset']['mywrapper']['#markup'] = 'test';
        return $form['fieldset']['mywrapper']['#markup'];
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code or your callback function ?

Comment: I added a snippet of the callback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've run into this problem a few times and it isn't a caching issue. The problem is you'll originally have a `<div>` wrapped around your `mywrapper` element, but in your ajax callback you're replacing it with a string...the `<div>` wrapper is therefore replace and next time you press the button the script can't find the `<div>` it needs to replace as it's not there any more!

Also, the arguments for your `mycallback` function need to be passed in by reference so change the signature to this: `function mycallback(&$form, &$form_state) {`.

Try making your code look a bit more like this:

```
function mymodule_my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset'
  );

  $form['fieldset']['my_element'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'Some initial markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="mywrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
  );

  $form['fieldset']['mybutton'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',   
    '#value' => t('Send request'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_mycallback',
      'wrapper' => 'mywrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',  
    )
  );

  return $form;
}


function mymodule_mycallback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['fieldset']['my_element']['#markup'] = 'New Markup';

  // Always, always, always return an element here, not a string.
  // This makes sure the form state stays consistent.
  return $form['fieldset']['my_element'];
}
```

If in doubt have a look at the [examples module](http://www.drupal.org/project/examples), specifically the `ajax_example_submit_driven_ajax()` example in the `ajax_example` module.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The solution was basically your last comment in the code: Returning the markup-item was the problem.

Comment: I run into this occasionally as well and think "it simply has to be caching" because of how it's appearing to anon users, but it always ends up being something specific in how the $form is handled or data is returned.

Comment: i checked the response via chrome dev console and looks to me like the situation described here, right data is coming in but my replacement doesn't work , although I tried the #markup work around

Comment: Someone give @Clive a cookie!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with help of the first answer

Add wrapper again

```
function mymodule_mycallback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['fieldset']['my_element']['#prefix'] = '<div id="mywrapper">';
  $form['fieldset']['my_element']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

 // Always, always, always return an element here, not a string.
 // This makes sure the form state stays consistent.
 return $form['fieldset']['my_element'];
}
```

And i don't think that u have to use the pointers (&) at least the drupal example module doesn't